# Configure a Repository on Spring via XML

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been surfing on Internet for hours trying to find a good example to configure a Spring's repository by using the XML instead of annotations (@Repository).

I found some good stuff (Hibernate 3):

> ```
> <!-- Hibernate interceptor to manage the session outside any transaction scope. -->
> <bean id="hibernateInterceptor"
>       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
>     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
> </bean>
>
> <!-- The configuration DAO -->
> <bean id="configurationDAO"
>       class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
>     <property name="target" ref="configurationDAOTarget"/>
>     <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="org.itracker.persistence.dao.ConfigurationDAO"/>
>     <property name="interceptorNames">
>         <list>
>             <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
>         </list>
>     </property>
> </bean>
>
> <bean id="configurationDAOTarget"
>       class="org.itracker.persistence.dao.ConfigurationDAOImpl">
>     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
> </bean>
> ```

But it seems that Hibernate 4 does not support `HibernateInterceptor` any longer.

Have any of you experience with this issue? A good solution? There's no other option rather than using the annotation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All `@Repository` does is meta-annotate a `@Component` and let the `org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` create an AOP proxy which does exception translation. At that level it's all Hibernate independent. The different implementations then understand their own exceptions and translate to the common Spring `DataAccessException` hierarchy.

In terms of doing it with XML, you'd have to somehow apply that proxy to the DAO beans you care about. Take a look at the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) manual for that, but it's going to be painful and not win you much.

For the sake of completeness, you can change the annotation from `@Repository` to something else, but as I read your question, you don't want to use annotations at all.

Comment: I'm a newbie in Spring and Hibernate. I'm just developing a personal "big" project combining both techs just for learning purposes. From the beginning my first point was to understand both implementations Annotations and XML, although the more I move forward the more I believe that Annotations are the preferred option form most developers.

Comment: The debate is typically about XML vs. annotation-based **configuration**, i.e. `@Configuration`. It's all hot air anyway. Use whatever suits you best. In general, people have migrated to annotation-based configuration because it's easier than XML for complex configurations, and just as simple as XML for simple ones, and the fact that it's code allows better reuse and composition. For the sake of your question, nothing prevents you from using `@Repository` with XML configuration, just remember to declare the PETPP as in http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate3-spring.